# How can I disable the macbook keyboard with Shift key held down on a password protected macbook?

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, keyboard, password, damage

This question is a bit strange, but here's the scenario:

- macbook air laptop with El Capitan Mac OS X
- currently logged off any account
- liquid damage on keyboard has caused shift key to be permanently pressed
- password to admin account has some lowercase letters and numbers
- restarting enters "safe mode"

The machine has no sensitive data, so I'm happy for a solution even if it wipes out the admin account. I'm also happy to buy a USB keyboard/plug into an external screen if that will help.

How can I disable this pesky shift key? Or disable the built in keyboard all together?

Comment: I found this for capslock, but idk how it might be modified for shift - https://github.com/mathiasbynens/dotfiles/issues/310 - maybe someone smarter than me can figure it out. [Though it does occur to me that you'd be typing it in all-caps;)

Answer (score 1):

Disable keyboard:

```
sudo kextunload /System/Library/Extensions/AppleUSBTopCase.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleUSBTCKeyboard.kext/
```

Enable keyboard:

```
sudo kextload /System/Library/Extensions/AppleUSBTopCase.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleUSBTCKeyboard.kext/
```

For manipulation, you can use the virtual keyboard:
System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard > Display panel "Keyboard" and "Symbols" in the menu bar

Answer (score -1):

same problem here, thought of changing the keyboard. make your login all CAPS letter and install karabiner software where you can disable left shift key..

Comment: Can you elaborate how the OP can make his login name all CAPS, given the state the machine is in as described in the question?